# Library for computing volumes of moderately high dimensional polytopes

Tags: library, c++

In my current code I need to calculate the volume of polytopes. These are moderately high dimensional (1D up to 15D).

The polytopes are represented in vertex representation, that is a matrix containing the coordinates of the vertices. Using cddlib I could also switch to hyperplane representation, that is Ax<=b, known from linear programming. I have been looking around for a C++ library that can calculate polytope volumes but I could not find one that supports objects in more than 3 dimensions and offers sufficient accuracy.

Any suggestion for such libraries?